# Grails and Jira Integration using RESTClient

Tags: grails, jira

I am using groovy http-builder and using RestClient for accessing web service from JIRA.
In development mode it's working fine but when I deploy war on Tomcat server it throws exception as

> "org.apache.commons.collections.map.ListOrderedMap: method ()V
>   not found. Stacktrace follows:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException:
>   Executing action [list] of controller [com.tristar.JiraController]
>   caused exception: Runtime error executing action
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException:
>   Runtime error executing action
>           ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.map.ListOrderedMap: method ()V
>   not found
>           at net.sf.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:1603)
>           at groovyx.net.http.EncoderRegistry.encodeJSON(EncoderRegistry.java:301)
>           at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate.setBody(HTTPBuilder.java:1200)
>           at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate.setPropertiesFromMap(HTTPBuilder.java:1111)
>           at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate.(HTTPBuilder.java:946)
>           at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.post(RESTClient.java:140)
>           at com.tristar.JiraController.list(JiraController.groovy:221)  "
>
> ```
> def jiraApiUrl = 'http://ipAddress:8080/rest/api/2/'
> def jiraClient = new RESTClient(jiraApiUrl)
>
> def searchResults = jiraClient.post(requestContentType: JSON,
>           path: 'search',
>           body: [jql: "project=XYZ AND (status=Open OR status='In Progress') AND issuetype!=Epic AND       issuetype!='Technical task'", startAt: offset, maxResults: params.max, fields: ['summary', 'description','issuetype']])
> ```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try to do full clean before build. `grails clean && rm -rf ./target/ && grails refresh-dependencies && grails war`. And additionally you may try to build by the next command `grails dev war`.

Comment: I had done all these things but no success. Any ways I have changed my implementation and it's working fine now.Thanks

Comment: Please describe your changes as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am added these dependencies in Build Config

```
compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-api:2.0.0-m25'
compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:2.0.0-m25'
```

and using

```
AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory()
def jiraServerUri = URI.create("ipaddress")
JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, "username", "password")
```

for authentication and getting RestClient object

Comment: that's nice.  It provides methods for the rest calls much like Bob Swift's soap API used to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using JIRA REST Client for JAVA in Grails application is not necessary, though it might have resolved your issue. I faced the same issue and was able to create a JIRA REST client with Groovy HTTP Builder.

The only dependency that I added in BuildConfig.groovy was:

```
dependencies {
 compile("org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.0-RC1") {
  excludes 'groovy', 'xml-apis' } }
```

Then build your JSON query and post your request:

```
jiraClient.post(requestContentType: JSON, body: query)
```

If you're looking for more info this blog post might help:

http://ashahrami.blogspot.ca/2014/12/jira-rest-client-implementation-in.html